# how to fetch latest record based on some parameter in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

i am trying fetch `latest` record based  on parameter but when use( `latest(), last(), earliest(), order_by('-id')[0], latest('-id')` )all this method in queryset then i got empty record, please help me out.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        category=request.query_params.get('category')
        name=request.query_params.get('name')
        try:
            d=Employee.objects.filter(category=category,name=name).latest()
            response_data=EmployeeSerializer(d,many=True).data
            return JsonResponse({"message": "detail retrieval","error":False,"code":200,"results":{"totalItems":d.count(),"pageData":response_data,"totalPages":1,"currentPage":0}}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "details not exist","error":True,"code":200,"results":{}}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        category=request.query_params.get('category')
        name=request.query_params.get('name')
        try:
            d=Employee.objects.filter(category=category,name=name).latest('id')
            serializer=EmployeeSerializer(d)
            return JsonResponse({"message": "detail retrieval","error":False,"code":200,"results":{"totalItems":d.count(),"pageData":serializer.data,"totalPages":1,"currentPage":0}}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "details not exist","error":True,"code":200,"results":{}}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).